# Bookmark syncing with Xmarks and iCloud

Tags: iphone, bookmarks, icloud, xmarks

I use Google Chrome for browsing on my computer and I have been using Xmarks to sync my bookmarks across browsers and computers. I would like to keep my iPhone's bookmarks synced as well.

So, the first solution that I came up with was to use Xmarks to sync my bookmarks to Safari and then to my phone through iTunes. This caused problems from time to time, messing up the order of bookmarks and adding default bookmarks that comes with Mobile Safari. (I think mostly because I cleaned out my device from time to time for iOS 5 betas.)

With iOS 5 released, this is happening more frequently and randomly since iCloud syncs bookmarks automatically. Has anyone found a good solution to this?